# Can you use strikethrough text in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, strikethrough

The title is the question, but here's a little background:

I'm making a task manager app for Android and want the user to be able to cross out tasks as they complete them onLongClick, without having to delete the task(which is already another feature). Normally, the user creates a task and I send the title, description and timeline to Firebase from that activity. Everything updates and all is well. The user can also edit and change any field in a separate activity and I am able to update Firebase just fine from that as well.

**My Problem**: I have it where it can successfully strikethrough the task title text for the user in my recyclerview that shows all the tasks. As soon as I push the update to Firebase, it changes the text to "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{c33...", which overwrites the original text.

[Without updating Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13nvb.png)

[After updating Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYx9O.png)

I'm not sure if what I want to do is even possible. If I simply cant strikeout text and store it on my database, what would be another good alternative to accomplish the same thing? I was thinking of just changing the timeline text to "complete" or something. I just prefer the strikethrough because it looks better to me and avoids having to open the task and manually edit the time.

Answer (score 1):

Databases, in general, do not store formatted text.  They just store plain text.  If you have some condition that you want to use to determine if text should be formatted in some way (like strikethrough), then I suggset storing another field, along with the text, that your code can use to determine how to format it.  In your case, a boolean field for "complete" would be all you really need.